# Light Projection passing through objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a light projector with a material attached to it and a script that projects a caustic effect underwater. Inside the script Inspector I have multiple caustics textures generated with by a software and it iterates in each of them changing the material texture of the projector.

**How can I make the shader behave more like light and be invisible on shadows?**

I have no experience in shaders and the shader is not from me.

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

```
Shader "Projector/Caustics" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,0)
        [NoScaleOffset]_MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "black" { }
        _Size ("Grid Size", Float) = 10
        _Height ("Water Height", Float) = 2.0
        _DepthBlend ("Depth Blend", Float) = 10.0
        _EdgeBlend ("Edge Blend", Range (0, 100)) = 0.5
        _Multiply ("Multiply", Range (1, 2)) = 1.0
        _LOD ("LOD Bias", Range (1, 1000)) = 100
     }

     Subshader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent+100" }
        Pass {
            ZWrite Off
            Offset -1, -1
            //Blend OneMinusDstColor One //- Soft Additive
            //Blend One One //- Linear Dodge
            Blend DstColor One

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float3 wPos : TEXCOORD1; // added for height comparisons.
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(2)
            };

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Color;
            float4x4 unity_Projector;
            float _Size;
            float _Height;
            float _DepthBlend;
            float _EdgeBlend;
            float _Multiply;
            float _LOD;
            float dist;

            v2f vert (appdata_tan v) {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
                o.wPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (mul (unity_Projector, v.vertex).xy, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR {
                dist = distance(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, i.wPos);
                fixed4 c = tex2Dlod (_MainTex, float4(fmod (i.uv, 1 / _Size)*_Size,0,dist/_LOD)); // project tiled texture, set lod.

                if (i.wPos.y<_Height) 
                    c = c-(i.wPos.y-_Height)/-_DepthBlend*2;
                else
                    c = lerp(c,0,(i.wPos.y-_Height)/_EdgeBlend);

                c = saturate(c);

                UNITY_APPLY_FOG_COLOR(i.fogCoord, c, fixed4(0,0,0,0));              
                return c * _Color *_Multiply ; // apply final color
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't have shadows with projectors, which is what you would need for this. Unity also doesn't support shadows for transparent object.

There are three options for achieving this effect:

- Use deferred decals, which are only supported in deferred mode.
- Use a screen-space effect.
- Create a custom terrain shader which displays the caustics as part of the terrain rendering based on the world space Y position. You would also need a similar shader modification to all other objects which are to receive caustics.

There are some examples on deferred decals in this [post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/06/extending-unity-5-rendering-pipeline-command-buffers/). Unfortunately though, without any knowledge of shader programming, it is not that straightforward to fix. There are some water solutions for Unity which have this feature built-in, though - for instance, [LUX](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/lux-water-119244) uses screen-space caustics which is pretty cool.